# Dynamically adding data to div from model on form dropdown select

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel, laravel-5, jquery-chosen

I've been searching for quite a while and can't find a solid answer for this. I'm using Laravel 5.3 as well as [Laravel Collective](https://laravelcollective.com/docs/5.2/html) for the forms and [Chosen](https://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/) to manipulate my select boxes.

Basically I have a select dropdown, which has values in it that are pulled from the database.
When I select a value, I wan't to populate each empty 'panel' on the page with the relevant model data for the selected item.

So for example when I select 'admin' I want to look in the 'roles' table and display 'description' and 'display_name' associated with the selected value. Furthermore I want to get the associated permissions for that entry and display them as well.

**Here is my form:**

```
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <script type="text/javascript">
                                    $(document).ready(function() {
                                        $(".role").chosen()
                                    });
                                </script>
                                {!! Form::label('Role') !!}
                                <div class="input-group">
                                    <div class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-user-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
                                    {!! Form::select('role', $roles, null, ['id' => 'role', 'class' => 'select-width-100 form-control role']) !!}
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            {!! Form::label('Display Name') !!}
                            <div class="panel panel-default">
                                <div class="panel-body" name="d_name" id="d_name">

                                </div>
                            </div>
                            {!! Form::label('Description') !!}
                            <div class="panel panel-default">
                                <div class="panel-body" name="description" id="description">

                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="input-group">
                              <span class="input-group-btn">
                                <button class="btn btn-danger" type="submit" name="update">Update</button>
                              </span>
                            </div>
```

I know there is a way to fire ajax and receive it with a 'route::get' but I have no idea how to do this or where to start. My Jquery skills are severely lacking.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

A bit of sample code, retrieve value only if role == admin when drop down changes.

```
    $('#role').on('change', function() {
        var role = $(this).val();
        if(role == 'admin') {

            $.ajax({
                 url : "{{url('role/details/')}}" + role, //your custom ajax get url
                 type: "GET",
                 success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR)
                 {
                    $("#d_name").html(data.name);
                    $("#description").html(data.description);
                  },
                  error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
                  {
                      alert("error");
                  }
             });
        }
    });
```

Controller:

```
public function getRoleDetails(Request $request)
{
    ...
    return response()->json(['name' => 'data data', 'description' => 'description description']);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First you have to create a partial which you will render on the controller according to your needs. Create a `div` which you will populate in success callback. e.g;

```
<div id='admin-information'></div>
```

I am not going to mention the controller code here. Here is the jQuery code.

```
$('body').on('change', '.my-select', function(){

$.ajax({
                'method' : 'get',
                'url'   : 'some url',
                'data' : {
                    'some_key' : $(this).data().val()
                },
                beforeSend: function(){},
                success: function(response){
                  $('#admin-information').html(response);
                },
                error: function(response){},
                complete: function(response){}
            });

});
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  Your answer seems to be on track with what I need. I just need some clarity on the values in the Jquery. what should the value of 'some_key' be ? as it is throwing an error when i set it as 'role'. Also, I need to output 2 values from the DB; 'display_name' and 'description'. Additionally, once my route has received the request, I should pass that to a controller and then send the values from the DB to the form ? Can I have a little more clarity on the process. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> Put options into select control best and easy way by form colletive.

Html

```
{{Form::select('ddl_school',['all'=>'Select all'], [], ['class'=>'form-control ddlsl'])}}
```

*Jquery function*

```
function getSchool(id) {
            $.ajax({
                type:'GET',
                url:'/ajaxRequest/getSchools/'+id,
                success:function(data){
                    if(data.success) {
                        $.each(data.data, function(index, value) {
                            **$('.ddlsl').append(new Option(value.name, value.locale_id));**
                        });
                    }
                },
                onError: function () {
                    alert('Something wants to wrong');
                }
            });
        }
```